# Query lenta sobre o MongoDB com índice

Tags: mongodb

Tenho uma coleção do MongoDB com cerca de 1,7 milhões de documentos, com média de 6kb por documento. O banco está em uma máquina razoável, com 6Gb de RAM e 4 CPUs

Essa coleção possui um índice sobre todos os campos da minha consulta.

O índice tem os atributos abaixo (String, String e Date) e tem o tamanho de míseros 15 mb. (Verifiquei pelo MongoDB Compass)

```
{
    "Unit" : 1.0,
    "VendorCode" : 1.0,
    "EmissionDate" : 1.0
}
```

No entanto, quando rodo qualquer query em cima da collection, mesmo que restrita aos atributos do índice, ela demora muito tempo para concluir.

Exemplo de Query

```
db.Collection.find({
        'Unit': '016406',
        'EmissionDate': {$gte: new ISODate('2018-08-01')}
    }, {
        'Unit': 1,
        'VendorCode': 1,
        'EmissionDate': 1
    })
```

Na minha experiência com SQL, uma consulta que está restrita a um índice deste tamanho retornaria resultado em frações de segundo. No entanto quando rodo a query, direto no shell ou com o Robo3T, ela leva mais de 10 minutos!

A impressão que me dá é que, mesmo os dados sendo contidos todos no índice, quando há match do documento, ele busca igual do storage.

Será que não estou levanto em conta algum preceito básico do MongoDB? Que opções me indicariam para investigar este problema?

Comment: Vc pode usar um aggregate e limpar os dados de retorno apenas para que vc quer.  replaceRoot ou project .

tenho consulta que o aggregate e melhor

Comment: A ordem dos atributos no índice e na consulta influência a busca. Você tem um índice com três níveis e está pulando um deles na consulta. Duas tentativas: 1. Tenta criar outro índice, que não tenha o campo VendorCode. 2. Ou tenta incluir o VendorCode na consulta. Aqui depende mais do teu modelo de negócio que está sendo representado, mas seria uma alternativa.

Comment: Estatisticas atualizadas ?